# Force installing torchvision 0.4.2 when I am forced to use pytorch 1.3.1 due to hardware constraints (ppc64le IBM)

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, ibm-cloud, conda, ppc64le

I am in a weird scenario were I am forced to use torch `1.3.1` (due to hardware see: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda/#/). I read from the pytorch docs that it's corresponding version of torchvision is `0.4.1` (https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/):

> ### Installation
>
> We recommend Anaconda as Python package management system. Please refer to [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/) for the detail of PyTorch (torch) installation. The following is the corresponding torchvision versions and supported Python versions.
>
> ```
> Installation
> We recommend Anaconda as Python package management system. Please refer to pytorch.org for the detail of PyTorch (torch) installation. The following is the corresponding torchvision versions and supported Python versions.
>
> torch torchvision python
> master / nightly  master / nightly    >=3.6
> 1.5.0 0.6.0   >=3.5
> 1.4.0 0.5.0   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.8
> 1.3.1 0.4.2   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
> 1.3.0 0.4.1   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
> 1.2.0 0.4.0   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
> 1.1.0 0.3.0   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
> <=1.0.1   0.2.2   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
> ```

but for some reason I have the wrong version of it:

```
torchvision 0.2.2 pypi_0 pypi
```

is there a way to install the right version of torchvision?

---

What I've tried:

First I tried force installing the right version with conda. Conda couldn't find the version of torchvision that I need:

```
$ conda install torchvision==0.4.2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - torchvision==0.4.2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-ppc64le
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Then I proceeded to try to install it regardless with pip

```
$ pip install torchvision==0.4.2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.4.2 (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.4.2
```

got an error too.

Is there anything else to try?

---

I tried but it failed:

```
conda install torchvision==0.4.2 -c pytorch

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - torchvision==0.4.2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-ppc64le
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-ppc64le
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

---

related:

- crossposted SO: [Force installing torchvision 0.4.2 when I am forced to use pytorch 1.3.1 due to hardware constraints (ppc64le IBM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64033543/force-installing-torchvision-0-4-2-when-i-am-forced-to-use-pytorch-1-3-1-due-to)
- crossposted pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/force-installing-torchvision/97279
- crossposted reddit pytorch: https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/iyf2qn/force_installing_torchvision/
- crossposted reddit ibm: https://www.reddit.com/r/IBM/comments/iyhzex/force_installing_torchvision_042_when_i_am_forced/
- real problem is installing torchmeta: https://github.com/tristandeleu/pytorch-meta/issues/95
- https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/forumsquestion?id=0D50z00006gaxV9CAI
- quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-does-one-install-specific-Python-packages-in-Conda-from-IBM-architectures
- reddit ibm2: https://www.reddit.com/r/newIBM/comments/iyij10/force_installing_torchvision_042_when_i_am_forced/
- gitissue for ibm: https://github.com/IBM/powerai/issues/268
  gitissue in pytorch

Comment: Adding channel via `-c pytorch` didn't help?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke do you mean `conda install torchvision==0.4.2 -c pytorch`? will try that now.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I tried installing pytorch from scratch with standard command `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` and that screwed up everything so I had to make the conda env the sys admins provided. The command looked similar to the one you suggested so I didn't try it. But I will now. It's still running... :/

Comment: @SzymonMaszke ok so doing `$ conda install torchvision -c pytorch` also changes my version of pytorch to `1.1.0`. That is why I didn't try that...what I need is a way to specify which version of torchvision to install. Ideally `0.4.2` using conda.

Comment: My command did pin the version `0.4.2` and I think it should work (`conda install torchvision==0.4.2 -c pytorch`). Also are you sure you need `0.4.2`? AFAIK `torchvision` isn't that strict dependent on pytorch version and should be fine.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke great questions! I cannot change the version to pytorch so I am stuck with `1.3.1` and that is 100% sure. Thats due to the IBM computer(s)/cluster/HPC I am using. But, for torchvision I can use whatever doesn't break things. The pytorch library I am trying to use (torchmeta) has a version that works with pytorch `1.3.1` and torchvision `0.4.2` which seem to be the ones that come together form the link I shared. This is the real issue I am trying to solve I guess: https://github.com/tristandeleu/pytorch-meta/issues/95

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I am rebuilding the conda environment. I will try your new suggestion `conda install torchvision==0.4.2 -c pytorch`. It seems like a sensible thing to try.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke why does it need the `-c pytorch` option? (asking while I wait for the env to rebuild and get insights into whats going on)

Comment: Specifies channel from which conda package will be downloaded. It won't find `torchvision` as it's not in the default conda channel (as it is a third party).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221963/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-charlie-parker).

Answer (score 1):

For all details check (https://github.com/IBM/powerai/issues/268).

Make sure you have the right conda channel prepended:

```
conda config --prepend channels https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda/#/
```

then install the powerai wmlce that you want e.g. 1.7.0 (most recent as of this writing):

```
conda create -n my_new_env python=3.7 powerai=1.7.0
conda activate my_new_env
```